# My DVD isn't being picked up by a working DVD drive

Tags: windows-10, dvd

I have a somewhat old DVD with Ship Simulator 2008 on it - I haven't used it in a couple of years but recently I decided to try install the game. However, when I put it in the DVD drive, I heard it started to work but then stopped and started again while Windows 10 gave no indication of anything happening. The last time I used the disk it was on Windows 7 but if it were incompatible or corrupt, shouldn't Windows give some sort of notification?

If the DVD is corrupt is there a way to recover the files? The companies that made the sim have moved on long ago so it would be really annoying if it was lost forever.

Comment: copy the file to USB or etc so you don't have to deal with the DVD again.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a while and putting the disk back in, it's suddenly decided to work - I have to clue why or how but I guess that's just Windows 10

Comment: It's equally likely to be the DVD or the drive dying, though as DVDs are pretty much a dead medium these days, now might be the time to get it backed up on something more reliable..

Comment: That is possible - my laptop is getting pretty old now; I mean it's a laptop with an inbuilt DVD drive which originally came with Windows Vista!